# Why is normalizing seasonal adjustment factors done additively?

Tags: forecasting, normalization, seasonality

One of the methods for dealing with seasonal influence is to establish a multiplicative factor for each season within a "year". For example, this happens with exponential smoothing models of type $(*,*,M)$. These adjustment factors need to be normalized - if there are $m$ seasons in a "year", then the seasonality normally represents only $m-1$ degrees of freedom.

The standard normalization requirement for adjustment factors $f_1, \dotsc, f_m$ seems to be to require that $\sum_{i=1}^m f_i = m$ - that is, the arithmetic mean of the factors is $1$. This is certainly the case in Hyndman et al., "Forecasting wtih Exponential Smoothing" (section 8.2).

I would have expected the requirement that the geometric mean be $1$, i.e., $\prod_{i=1}^m f_i = 1$. This because the standard for *additive* seasonal adjustment is that $\sum_{i=1}^m f_i = 0$; these two are equivalent under taking logarithms. Is there a good mathematical reason for the choice, or is it just a convention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make much difference in practice. But your suggested multiplicative adjustment is more consistent with the way the seasonal factors are used in ETS(*,*,M) models.

Comment: I know this is old but I didn't find any other question on this matter. If we have an estimate of the trend. Wouldn't multiplicative (product=1) seasonal normalization be more appropriate only if the trend estimate is centered on the geometric mean of the data (ie. if the log(trend) is centered on the arithmetic mean of the log transformed data)? And would additive (mean=1) normalization be more appropriate if the trend estimate is centered on the arithmetic mean of the data?

Answer (score 2):

It may depend on the context.

Suppose you are seasonally adjusting something like quarterly GDP.  This makes sense multiplicatively because all the figures now are roughly a multiplicative factor higher (based on inflation and growth) than they were some years ago.

But if you want the seasonally adjusted figures for the four quarters to add up to the actual annual total (to avoid having to explain what a different "seasonally adjusted annual total figure" might mean) then you may need need to normalise the seasonal adjustments additively.